# Django eternicode bootstrap-datepicker doesn't work on phones

Tags: django, bootstrap-datepicker

In my Django app i'm using bootstrap-datepicker. User chooses a date, then date is passed in Ajax post request to /check/ view, then sub_template is reloaded with retrieved data.

Everything works like a charm on desktop, but it seems like datepicker doesn't work on phones at all. I've tested it on Iphone 6s, android phone and windows phone(all default browsers). When i press date it just doesn't respond in any way.

Here is my main page  html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
         <h2>Availability</h2>
    </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row text-center hidden-xs ">
        </div>

        <div class="row row-pad-30 text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-1 md-hidden"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h3>1. Choose date</h3>
                <form style="color: white;" class="form-date" role="form" action="" method="get">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group" id="datepicker">
                        <div></div>
                        <input data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" type="hidden" name="dt_due" id="dt_due" val="">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="refresh-div" class="timedisplay">{% include 'booking/time.html' %}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 md-hidden"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

sub page html:

```
<div class = "col-lg-6">
    <h3  class = "h3-hour">2. Choose hour</h3>
    <div class="row row-pad-20">
        {% for time_list in availability_table %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            {% for i in time_list %}
                 <button type="submit" class="fade-in-quick btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info btn-core" value="{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="time" id="time">{{ i.0|date:'H:i' }} do {{ i.1|date:'H:i' }}</button> 
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

main page script:

```
$('#datepicker div').datepicker({
    language:"pl",
    startDate: "+1d"
}).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    var date = event.format()
    console.log(date);
    $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url: '/check/',
         data: {'date': date, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()},
         success: function(data) {
         $('#refresh-div').html(data);
         }
        });
    });
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this div:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Was causing problems. When i just deleted all classes after col-lg-4(they are not necessary anyway) everything is working correctly.